How to create a deck of cards with 3 nested lists?
I need to create a deck of cards that has 3 values at each index; one for card value, one for suit and one for card name. Ideally, I could have a num_deck variable that would add more decks when I change it. The order of values, names, suites within a list element does not matter.
values = [11, 10, 10, 10, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2]
names = ["A", "K", "Q", "J", "10", "9", "8", "7", "6", "5", "4", "3", "2"]
suits = ['Spade', 'Heart', 'Diamond', 'Club']

Intended result format:
[[10, 'J', 'Spade'], [10, '10', 'Heart'], [8, '8', 'Spade']], etc. 

At first, I used:
list(itertools.product(range(1,14), ['Spade', 'Heart', 'Diamond', 'Club']))

which worked until I needed to add the 3rd number to each element. I couldn't find a way to modify it to get the way I wanted. I also tried appended the 3 lists provided above which isn't cutting it.

You can self-answer.  Don't put the answer in the question.

This created the right list:
deck = list((*a,b) for a,b in itertools.product(zip(values, names), suits)) * num_deck

